# Symbols used in a dictionary

Tags: usage, dictionaries, symbols

I came across this little bar located on lower part of a word in a dictionary, and I am wondering what it means.
Unfortunately even my keyboard doesn't have the symbol so that I can show you.

It looks like this mark ' on the lower part of a word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symbols used should be explained in the dictionary. If it was a printed dictionary, then usually at the beginning.

Upper and lower marks resembling apostrophes or commas are often used to denote primary and secondary stress (placed before the stressed syllable). So this may be the case, but I can't tell for certain without seeing it.

For example, in this screenshot of the ["Revolutionary" entry from the online Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revolutionary),
[image: as stated]

it says that the primary stress is on the third syllable, and first and fifth syllable get secondary stresses.